# Listing a Summary with limits

Tags: command-line, grep, sort, cut, syslog

I am trying to list a number of offending IP's with a one line command, and am not sure how to do the last little bit, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

```
cat /var/log/syslog* | grep "SRC=" | cut -d " " -f 14 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

In English...this should print all syslog files (also those rotated), search for entries of the Firewall and grab the SRC value (IP), count them and list them from highest to lowest. All I want now is to limit it to the top 5... Anybody know a command that can do that ?

Example entry in syslog:

> Jan 11 12:01:52 xxxx kernel: [47261.722647] INPUT packet died: IN=eth0
>   OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:a0:24:eb:00:31:46:0d:21:e8:08:00 SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx
>   DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=33840 PROTO=TCP
>   SPT=1024 DPT=22151 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

*The entries are made by my custom Firewall, not part of this Question*

Example output of the command:

> ```
>  47 SRC=13.82.59.79
>   2 SRC=77.72.82.145
>   2 SRC=213.157.51.11
>   2 SRC=159.203.72.216
>   1 SRC=77.72.85.15
>   1 SRC=77.72.85.10
>   1 SRC=77.72.83.238
>   1 SRC=77.221.1.237
>   1 SRC=222.186.172.43
>   1 SRC=216.170.126.109
>   1 SRC=191.101.167.253
>   1 SRC=190.198.183.234
>   1 SRC=173.254.247.206
>   1 SRC=164.52.13.58
>   1 SRC=141.212.122.145
>   1 SRC=125.78.165.42
>   1 SRC=118.139.177.119
>   1 SRC=111.75.222.141
>   1 SRC=103.30.40.9
> ```

Comment: Is it a `head -n 5` you need as an extra step at the end of the pipeline, or did I misunderstand what you meant by "the top five"?

Comment: in your "example entry" the crucial item `SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx` is the 13th field, while you are cutting it as 14th field `cut -d " " -f 14` , why?

Comment: also, `cat | grep | cut` when just `awk` will do??  Try, e.g `awk '/SRC=/ {print $13}' /var/log/syslog | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest because `cut` isn't smart about whitespace.  `-d ' '` means **exactly** one space character, not one-or-more.  It's one of the reasons i prefer to use `awk` rather than cut.

Comment: I just learned to give head in Linux ..... XD

Comment: some would say that's a useful skill in any language.

Comment: @cas, he can't rely on 14th or whatever field number with `cut -d'  '` in case of arbitrary multiple spaces

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, that is true.  that's another reason why i prefer not to use `cut` except in the very simplest of cases (or, at least, not until **after** the input data has been transformed into some consistent, predictable shape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/SRC=/ { print $13 }' /var/log/syslog* | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

This does away with the catting, grepping and cutting from the original pipeline and replaces them with `awk`.  The `head -n 5` at the end will give you the top five results.

Answer (score 0):

With single GNU **`awk`** "magic":

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" 
     }
     /SRC=/{ src[$13]++ }
     END{ 
         for (k in src) { 
             print src[k], k; 
             if (++c > 4) break 
         } 
     }' /var/log/syslog*
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `perl` (no need for `grep`, `cut`, `sort`, or `uniq`):

```
perl -lane '
  $IPs{$F[12]}++ if (m/SRC=/);  # perl arrays start from zero, not 1.

  END {
    foreach $ip (sort { $IPs{$b} <=> $IPs{$a} } keys %IPs) { 
      last if ($count++ > 4);

      $seen=$IPs{$ip};   # $seen is only really needed in case you uncomment 
                         # the next line, to use the key before we change it.

      #$ip =~ s/^SRC=//; # uncomment if you want IPs without the SRC=

      printf "%s\t%s\n", $seen, $ip;
    };
  }' < <(zcat /var/log/syslog*)
```

It builds a hash array (`%IPs`) counting each time it sees a particular IP address.  After it's read all the input, it sorts the hash by the count, and prints the top 5.

BTW, this uses `zcat` rather than just `/var/log/syslog*` because it's common for syslog and other log files to be rotated and compressed regularly.