# Finding a string with awk and printing the match on word boundry

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am a little new to awk, so this question might have been asked, but I can't find a solution to my Question.

Using awk, I would like to search for a string in syslog, and only print the value until the next word boundary.

> Rules:
>
> - Only awk can be used
> - Should be a one line Command in Linux

Test Data:
Syslog contains entries made by the Firewall when packets are dropped. These lines of information contains multiple values and vary in length (forget NF). 
**The source IP always start with SRC=**

What I have so far:

```
awk '/SRC=/ { print $13 }' /var/log/syslog*
```

The problem however is that Field 13 is not always the SRC value.

The rest of the solution can be seen in this Question: [Listing a Summary with  limits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416326/listing-a-summary-with-a-limits)

Comment: Out of interest - why are you fixed on `awk`?

Comment: Do you really mean ["word boundary"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) or do you want to print until the end of the field (until the next whitespace in awk, by default, or whatever you have set `IFS` to)? Please [edit] your question and show us an actual example of your input data and your desired output.

Comment: nice link for word boundary ;) Yes, that is what I meant. The Target text is in format SRC=192.168.1.1, no spaces, and the default in awk is too use spaces as the IFS. To see a example look at the linked Question please.

Comment: @Sobrique just trying to improving my skill in the Linux basics, awk  and sed has been due for some time now ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='SRC=[^[:space:]]+' 'NF{ print $1 }' /var/log/syslog*
```

This will narrow processing records to only one field matching the pattern `SRC=[^[:space:]]+`

---

Time performance check (`testlog` has 22756 lines):

```
$ time(awk -v FPAT='SRC=[^[:space:]]+' 'NF{ print $1 }' testlog > /dev/null)

real    0m0.186s
user    0m0.164s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time(awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^SRC=/) print $i}}' testlog > /dev/null)

real    0m0.282s
user    0m0.256s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Changing your logic `SRC=[^[:space:]]+` to `SRC=.{7,15}[[:space:]]+` almost works...

Comment: adding `{ if(length($1)) print $1 }` to the print logic, solves the problem, but it's not sexy :(

Comment: @WillemP.Botha, this `SRC=.{7,15}[[:space:]]+` is wrong, cause `.`(dot) matches ANY character including whitespace(s)

Comment: @WillemP.Botha, if your files may contain records without `SRC=...` field - use my update, it'll work fine

Comment: +1. BTW, GNU awk understands the PCRE `\S` shorthand for `[^[:space:]]` so this could be written as `awk -v FPAT='SRC=\\S+' 'NF{ print $1 }'`   (note the double-backslash in the FPAT - it's required here).   Also, `-v FPAT='SRC=[0-9.]+'` works.

Answer (score 3):

KISS solution (should work in any awk flavor) - simply loop over the fields and test one-by-one:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^SRC=/) print $i}}' /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: optimization hint: `if ($i ~ /^SRC=/) { print $i; break }`